# How to write reusable apps with customizable models in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to make reusable apps, that allow for customization by the integrator.

An example is if I make a newsletter signup app with the bare minimum of storing email address, but the integrator later wants to add additional fields, like say a name. What is the things I need to do to allow for this easily?

I went down the path of swapping out the models, like Django's auth system does, but that didn't work well. Then I found swappable attribute in the Meta class [and a package that does this](https://github.com/wq/django-swappable-models), but both are not intended for external use.

The only way I can think of for the integrator to do is, allow them to provide custom forms by passing it into the view in the urls for instance.

```
url('^someurl/$', MyView.as_view(form_class=SomeForm), name="myurl")
```

Then have a secondary model, with foreign keys to the internal newsletter model, but this means a secondary table that needs to be joined.

Another alternative is to try Abstract models, but I'm not sure what the impact will be there.

So what is the Django/Pythonic way of solving this?